# How redirect php Window.location.href or Window.open () methods in php and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, window.open, window.location

I follow up a tutorial to learn more about php, in it's source code there is something which seems works at that time but not anymore. here is the code , please let me know what should i change in the code in order to make login process work (currently after entering a valid user name and pass  and clicking login it freezes and show first page and not go to home.php

here is template/header.php:

```
<div class="container">
        <!--Head wrap starts-->
        <div id="head_wrap">
            <!--Header starts-->
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left;"/>
                <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
                    <strong>Email:</strong>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
                    <strong>Password:</strong>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="****" required="required"/>
                    <button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--Header ends-->
        </div>
```

here is login.php

```
<?php
        session_start();

        include("includes/connection.php");

        if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

        $get_user = "select * from users where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'";

        $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_user);

        $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

        if($check==1){
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

            $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

                        echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";



        }
            else {
            echo "<script>alert('Passowrd or email is not correct!')</script>";
        }

        }
?>
```

please note i have tried

```
        echo "<script> window.location.href = 'home.php';</script>";
```

instead of

```
        echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
```

and still doesn't work, since it's tutorial and i have search through stackoverflow can't find any answer i appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the submit button?  I only see a normal button.  Until you submit the page PHP will not run at all.  And you should use the PHP 'header' command to redirect the page, not Javascript.

Comment: @CharlesEF i have tried submit button but that one is not only the bug it has , can you please let me know what other bug the tutorial has

Comment: I tried to download the file but I can't get past the social media part.  I'm asked to download the file using Facebook, Twitter or Goggle+.  Since I don't do any social media at all I'm not going to sign up just to download your file.  If you can place the file on another server maybe I can download it, just not from the current location.

Comment: You are using a web server aren't you?  PHP only runs server side so you need to have a web server working.  And PHP must be installed on the web server.

Comment: I don't use sites like that so I don't have one to recommend to you, sorry.  If you can find another site just post the address in a comment.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Give me some time to go over everything.

Comment: is your header.php is included in home.php ?

Comment: @jigar halani i have added, no change is made by doing that, still empty page( login.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your HTML code but with a submit button.  You say all files are located in the same folder so this should work.  I did not make any changes to login.php but it should run when the page is submitted.

```
<div class="container">
 <!--Head wrap starts-->
 <div id="head_wrap">
  <!--Header starts-->
  <div id="header">
   <img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left;"/>
   <form method="post" action="login.php" id="form1">
    <strong>Email:</strong>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <strong>Password:</strong>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="****" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login">
   </form>
  </div>
  <!--Header ends-->
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**  I can't debug your entire project but after looking over some things I see you are not using the 'name' attribute.  When a page is submitted a name/value pair is sent in the $_POST array.  If you have no 'name' attribute nothing is sent.  Start by adding the 'name' attribute.  I have modified the above HTML code to show you how.

Comment: i have tried to add submit type to input and the value but this is not the only issue cause not working. if you can please take a look at Edit2 and see what other error it has is much appreciated. i have struggling two days with this code and can't find the reason

Comment: after adding name and action="login.php" in the form, the url will redirect to login.php and white empty page. i think the case is i need to modify correct php files in the action form, i tried action="home.php" but it doesn't go to home.php it remains in index.php. can you please take a quick look and let me know what php should i add to action? if you want to run the code , you will find mysqli_connect configuration connections in include/connections.php and function/functions.php and delete_post.php. Thanks –

Comment: There are many other problems with you code that I didn't mention but should have.  I don't see you do any data validation, on the Javascript side or PHP side.  You should always validate user input.  Since you use mysqli_* commands you should use parameterized queries, to help protect against SQL injections.  As for the action script, I put login.php in the action attribute because that is the script that will handle the user login.  Have you looked in the PHP error log?  That might give you an idea where the problem is.

Comment: I looked at your login.php and HTML code you posted first.  I see the submit button has no 'name' attribute, it needs one because of this line in login.php 'if(isset($_POST['login'])){'.  Without the 'name' then $_POST['login'] will not exist and the PHP will not run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [header(...)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) function but don't forget that your page keep to run at the end. Don't forget to use with `die` to stop your script. ;)

```
die(header("Location: home.php"))
```

or after 5 seconds :

```
header("refresh: 5; url=home.php");
```

Comment: sorry not working , i attach the entire source code of the project in edit2 in main question , please let me know if you have any idea. thanks

Comment: @Jack It's cookie function like session start ok SET_COOKIE you must don't have HTML output before. Or use html to redirect like this `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.php" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($check==1){
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

        $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

                    return 1;
   }
        else {
         return 0;
    }
```

and javascript check status 1 and 0 then window.location.href and window.open use

Comment: using ajax success

Comment: can you please complete your code with ajax success and window.location.href and window.open , it helps me to exactly catch what you are meaning if you wirte it completely in code. if it works i accept your answer as this thread

Answer (score -1):

Check in your file..

> 1) header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by
>   normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP
>
> 2) Combine all your PHP codes and make sure you don't have any spaces
>   at the beginning of the file.
>
> 3) after header('location: home.php'); add exit();
>
> 4) after sesssion_start() add ob_start();